# Canny filter gives strange results, in ITK (concentric borders)

Tags: image-processing, filtering, itk

*[The issue is solved using another filter, see the update at the bottom.]*

I am working with C++ and ITK, and I have a greyscale image, representing the bone map of a lumbar spine. I am trying to detect its border using a Canny filter: for this purpose, I am using the [Canny filter implementation](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/Filtering_2CannyEdgeDetectionImageFilter_8cxx-example.html#_a5) from the official ITK's guide (I am using that code as is, so I do not paste it here). As you can see, the input image is really simple, and it shouldn't be difficult to extract its contour that way.

I am expecting an output image totally black, except for the bone's border, that should be a closed curve. However, ITK produces the result that you can see in the image on the right, consisting in *multiple*, "concentric" borders.

How do you explain this result? Do you have a formal explanation about what's going on with that algorithm? I have tried to modify the filter's parameters (variance, upperThresold and lowerThresold), but without luck. Some combinations of parameters give a totally black image, and none of them gives a result better that this one.

[image: Bone map of a lumbar spine - Grayscale image]
[image: Strange result of Canny filtering]

**UPDATE**: Just as a note, I solved using a "[Gradient Magnitude Filter](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/EdgesAndGradients/GradientMagnitudeImageFilter)". With that filter, I obtain a well-defined shape for the contour. So, the issue is no longer critical for me, but I keep the post open, just for the sake of curiosity. If you have any idea regarding the Canny filter's behaviour, I can test it.

Comment: You mentioned this image was grayscale. Have you tried binarizing it and then applying the filter? Is this a 16 bpp grayscale image? If so then it is possible that the image actually has those edges but the current window/level (if applied) doesn't show those edges (the output of window/level is 8 bpp)?

Comment: @ananthonline: Thank you so much...but I think that the image is in 8bpp already :-( If I select File Properties, clicking with the right mouse button on the file, and I go under "Details", I see *Bit Depth: 8*. I think that you intended that.